# Better way to Get Property Than using Lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

So we have this crap all over in our code, IMO too much lodash.  For example:

```
const profileId = _.get(account, 'profileId', null);
const player = _.get(someCustomObject, 'player'); // Why??????  why not just someCustomObject.player?
```

Is it me or is it ridiculous to be using lodash for everything when you can just access object properties by the object!  In general we're using lodash and it's overkill in many places and makes the code way more verbose and hard to read.

In this case, we don't really need lodash either:

```
const profileId = _.get(account, 'profileId', null);
```

What would be a way to do that without lodash?  That's my question.  Here are a few thoughts:

```
const profileId = (account && account.profileId) || null
```

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

Interesting, went with Ori's answer but just an observation here.  I wanted to remove defaulting the `profileId` to null just because I feel it's unnecessary.  But why didn't this set `profileId` to the account object?

```js
const account = {};
const game = { player: 'Sam' }

console.log(`account: ${account}`);

const { profileId } = account || {};
const { player } = game || {};

console.log(`profileId: ${profileId} // why is this undefined if account has value {}???`);
console.log(`player: ${player}`);
```

Even though account is set to a literal, I still get `undefined` for `profileId` above.  That's weird..?

*FINAL SOLUTION*
(run this in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io) since you'll need lodash loaded)

```
console.log(" Example Clean Code without Lodash")
console.log('===============================')

let account = {};
const game = { player: 'Sam' }

console.log(`account: ${account}`);

const { profileId = null } = account;
const { player } = game || {};

console.log(`profileId: ${profileId}`);
console.log(`player: ${player}`);

/* using IIFE so profileId doesn't conflict with example above */
(() => {
  console.log("Example using unnecessary Lodash")
  console.log('===============================')

  let profileId = _.get(account, 'profileId', null);
  const game = { player: 'Sam' } 

  console.log(`account2: ${account}`);

  const { player } = game || {};

  console.log(`profileId: ${profileId}`);
  console.log(`player: ${player}`);
})();
```

Comment: "Better" is a broad term.

Comment: > Even though account is set to a literal, I still get undefined for profileId above. That's weird..?
I would expect that since `const { profileId } = account || {};` is equivilent to this `const profId = (account || {}).profileId;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lodash's `_.get()` is really good if you want to get something nested inside an object `profile.player.id` for example, and it also has a default if nothing is found or there's an error, like this example `_.get(account, 'profileId', null);`.

If it's a direct property of the object, you can use [destructuring with a default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```js
const account = {};
const game = { player: 'Sam' }


const { profileId = null } = account || {};
const { player } = game || {};

console.log(profileId);
console.log(player);
```

In vanilla JS you can use [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: 42,
    },
  },
};
 
const baz = obj?.foo?.bar?.baz; // 42
 
const safe = obj?.qux?.baz; // undefined
```

Comment: Neither of these are entirely alternatives for `_.get()` because they would both throw an error if `account` or `game` were `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: right, but mine would work: `const profileId = (account && account.profileId) || null`

Comment: I just want to get rid of all the unecessary _get() even if it might be null.  I'm finding all those very verbose in our code, the code is already messy enough

Comment: right yea I was thinking the same, your last edit, that works.. or even `const { profileId = null } = account || null;`

Comment: @JLRishe - indeed. I've added a fallback for `null` and `undefined`. And still, it won't cover everything `_.get()` does.

Comment: but clearly this is stupid `const player = _.get(window, 'player');`.  Just do `window.player`.  I feel like the devs on this team just blindly follow existing code without using their heads (just mimic how every other person's done without thinking "clean code")

Comment: But that is not - `const player = _.get(window, 'player.user.data.id', null);`

Comment: well that'd just be `window.player.user.data.id`

Comment: @PositiveGuy How is that so different from your other example? `window.player` will throw an error if `window` is `null` or `undefined`, so you would need `const player = window && window.player` or something like what Ori has.

Comment: it's just cleaner, you don't need the get() and all that crap.  Just use the freakin object and prop.  lodash gives us nothing in that case, but clutter.  if you remove chars your code becomes cleaner, and that's a very good case of using lodash where you don't need to

Comment: And it this case `window.player.user.data.id` you'll need - `window && window.player && window.player.user && window.player.user.data && window.player.user.data.id`.

Comment: correct, but lodash isn't gaining us anything right?  regardless in that case?  Like lodash isn't going to return a null if window is null...it will still blow up

Comment: compare this to `_.get(window, 'player.user.data.id', null)`. If there's an error, lodash will fallback to the default value.

Comment: I see...hmm, I guess `const player = _.get(window, 'player', null);` might make more sense then but just `const player = _.get(window, 'player');` to me makes me go ???

Comment: @PositiveGuy It didn't occur to me that the `window` in your example is referring to the browser's global `window` object. Seems like that's not a great example because you should (ideally) not be storing too many things on the global window object in the first place.

Comment: well yea (that's another example of the "mess" in our codebase), but pretend that's not window and is a custom object just for the sake of conversation :).  I updated my post...

Comment: uh I hate foo/bar examples but thanks.  I think we've over used dumb foo bar :P. proposal-optional-chaining looks awesome though.  However for stuff like React, having required props defined is also part of elevating some of the pain

Comment: I'd prefer my stuff to be undefined personally not null anyway: `const { profileId } = account || {};` so I'd prefer profileId to just simply be undefined in the first place.  Less code as well here.

Comment: I'm ultimately going with `const { profileId = null } = account;`.  It'll never populate the {}, that || never gets hit for `const { profileId = null } = account || {};`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice one-liner from the article "[Safely Accessing Deeply Nested Values In JavaScript](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/safely-accessing-deeply-nested-values-in-javascript-99bf72a0855a)"

```
export function _get(object, path, defval = null) {
    if (typeof path === "string") path = path.split(".");
    return path.reduce((xs, x) => (xs && xs[x] ? xs[x] : defval), object);
}
```

You may also use this awesome library of zero dependency utilities
https://github.com/angus-c/just

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for this case:
         _get({p:{a:[0,1,2,3]}}, 'p.a[1]')
while lodash works

Comment: function _get(object, path,defval) {
        if (typeof path === "string") path = path.split(".");
        return path.reduce((xs, x) => (xs && xs[x]?xs[x]:x.split("[").reduce( (xxs, xx) =>(xxs && xxs[xx.replace(/(.*)\]/,'$1')]? xxs[xx.replace(/(.*)\]/,'$1')]:defval),xs)), object);
    }
// it is far to be elegant

Comment: @DanieleCruciani you can always just `_get({a: [1, 2]}, 'a.1')`... if you have to be "lodash compatible" you can do `path = path.replace(/\[/g, '.').replace(/\]/g, '').split('.')`

Answer (score 2):

`_.get` is a helper method that is used for several reasons. It helps you reduce code/logic duplication, it's harder to make an error and easier to read and maintain your code.

If you are worried about the performance difference between `_.get` and `(account && account.profileId) || null`, I don't think you should be worried unless you have a huge codebase that calls `_.get` hundreads of times. Here is the lodash's `get` function definition and it's dependancies.

```
function get(object, path, defaultValue) {
  var result = object == null ? undefined : baseGet(object, path);
  return result === undefined ? defaultValue : result;
}

function baseGet(object, path) {
  path = castPath(path, object);

  var index = 0,
      length = path.length;

  while (object != null && index < length) {
    object = object[toKey(path[index++])];
  }
  return (index && index == length) ? object : undefined;
}

function castPath(value, object) {
  if (isArray(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  return isKey(value, object) ? [value] : stringToPath(toString(value));
}

function toKey(value) {
  if (typeof value == 'string' || isSymbol(value)) {
    return value;
  }
  var result = (value + '');
  return (result == '0' && (1 / value) == -INFINITY) ? '-0' : result;
}
```

You can always perform a benchmark test for your code with 2 different variations and then decide if it makes enough difference for you to use the native implementation.

I just did a benchmark test where lodash's `._get` was **95%** slower than the native implementation. I guess you can afford that unless your code heavily relies on `._get` as stated above.
Maybe even better alternative would be to write your own helper function to get rid of the lodash's overhead and achieve the same pros of lodash's `get` and also near-native performance. You can define your own helper function knowing in advance what kind of data will be passed to it, thus writing a zero-overhead helper for your specific usecase.

Comment: >easier to read and maintain your code.  I'd argue it's verbose...and puts a heavy footprint on your codebase if you're using it like hell all over.

Comment: >unless you have a huge codebase that calls _.get hundreads of times.  Yup, we do have that :).  That's why I posted this in the first place, I prefer my option, and to stop overly using lodash, I want less of a footprint on lodash and just use the damn language.  I also get sick of people forgetting to add imports for lodash in our files.

Comment: >Maybe even better alternative would be to write your own helper function to get rid of the lodash's overhead and achieve the same pros of lodash's get and also near-native performance.  I like that idea better

Comment: I am ultimately going with `const { profileId = null } = account;`.  Simple, clean, easy to read, no lodash necessary.

Comment: @PositiveGuy But if `account` is undefined then it'll throw an exception - `_.get(account, 'profileId')` would prevent that issue. Once the null/undefined [coalescence feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) makes its way into ES, we'll have a much better solution: `const profileId = account?.profileId ?? null`

Answer (score 0):

This come out from a recent discussion:

```
var template = "string with {obj.prop} first of 0: {results[0].first}";
var data = {obj: {prop: 'mine'}, results:[{first:'f'},{first:'ff'}] }
var regex = /{(.*?)}/g;
var str = template.replace(regex, (e, key) => _.get(data, key, ''));
console.log(str);
```

but you can write a function:

```
const interpolate = (template, data) => template.replace(/{(.*?)}/g, (e, key) => _.get(data, key, ''));
```

of cource it is simpler to use:

```
let str = interpolate("string with {obj.prop} first of 0: {results[0].first}", data)
```

in general in everywhere you do not know what you are going to replace, _.get() is something good to have.

*UPDATE*: fix the missing regexp!

Comment: and replace _.get with _get() from @xpuu, so we have a 2 line code for string interpolation